# Can not get correct bounding box on svg to trim white space

Tags: python, svg

Quick note before the question: at this current time, `svgelements` (the Python library) is not a tag on SO, so I can not include it in this question. This being said, a solution doesn't have to exclusively use `svgelements`, nor use it at all.

---

I am trying to use the `svgelements` library to load a svg, get the bounding box that contains all of the elements with respect to their transformations, then set the viewBox of the svg to be that bounding box, as a method to trim all the white space around the elements. Here is what I have so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
import svgelements as se

def get_bbox(svg_file):
    svg_file = Path(svg_file)
    print(svg_file.name)
    svg = se.SVG.parse(str(svg_file))

    bb = svg.bbox()
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = bb
    width = maxx - minx
    height = maxy - miny

    # set the height and width of the physical size of the svg
    # I just make it the same as the viewbox width and height
    view_box = se.Viewbox(f"{minx} {miny} {width} {height}")
    svg.values["attributes"]["height"] = str(view_box.height)
    svg.values["height"] = str(view_box.height)
    svg.values["attributes"]["width"] = str(view_box.width)
    svg.values["width"] = str(view_box.width)

    svg.viewbox = view_box

    # add a border around the svg to see if the contents are in the right place.
    if "style" not in svg.values["attributes"]:
        svg.values["attributes"]["style"] = ""

    if "border" not in svg.values["attributes"]["style"]:
        svg.values["attributes"]["style"] += "border: solid black 1px;"

    svg.write_xml(str(svg_file.with_stem(svg_file.stem + "-new")))
```

[This](https://freesvg.org/gravure-link-not-afraid-geek-nintendo) is the svg that I am having problems with.

I've only tested this method out on 1 other svg, that seemed more basic with its mark-up, and it worked *well*. This one is more complicated, and I'd like to get it to work. Is there something that I am overlooking or is it just the svg? I've been able to successfully use chrome and the inspector to get the actual bounding box and set it to the viewBox (of course, those numbers are different than what is returned from the `svgelements` library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-hah! I figured it out!

1. Get the bounding box of the svg.
2. Break it up into xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax, so you can get the height and width
3. Set `svg.x` to equal xmin, `svg.y` to ymin, `svg.height` to height, and `svg.width` to width.

```
from pathlib import Path
import svgelements as se

def get_bbox(svg_file):
    svg_file = Path(svg_file)
    print(svg_file.name)
    svg = se.SVG.parse(str(svg_file))

    bb = svg.bbox()
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = bb
    width = maxx - minx
    height = maxy - miny

    # set the height and width of the physical size of the svg
    # I just make it the same as the viewbox width and height
    view_box = se.Viewbox(f"{minx} {miny} {width} {height}")
    svg.x = view_box.x
    svg.y = view_box.y
    svg.height = view_box.height
    svg.width =  view_box.width

    svg.write_xml(str(svg_file.with_stem(svg_file.stem + "-new")))
```

Too bad I couldn't figure how to add a `style` attribute to the svg, without having to use another library...